# $\frac{d}{dx}\left(\int f(x) dx\right) \neq \int \frac{d}{dx}f(x) dx\ ?$

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives

I was playing around with derivatives and integrals and I noticed this:

$$\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\left(\int f(x) \mathrm{d}x\right)=\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\left(F(x) + C\right)=f(x)$$

where $F(x)$ is the antiderivative of $f(x)$. But:

$$\int \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}f(x) \mathrm{d}x=\int f'(x) \mathrm{d}x=f(x) +C$$

Does this mean that:

$$\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\left(\int f(x) \mathrm{d}x\right) \neq \int \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}f(x) \mathrm{d}x\ ?$$

I've learned that the derivative is the inverse of the integral and it makes sense that $f(f^{-1}(x))=f^{-1}(f(x))$

Comment: Careful with the writing of variables : here $x$ stands for what ? What is the variable of the function "$\int f(x)\mathrm{d}x$ ?"

Comment: Interchanging limits is risky business. See dominated convergence theorem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That pesky $+C$ makes antiderivatives non-unique. 
 $\int f(x)\; dx$ is not just one function, it is a whole family of them.
So it's inaccurate to say that differentiation is the inverse of integration.

If you remove the non-uniqueness by using definite integrals, they're still not equal.

$$ \dfrac{d}{dx} \int_0^x f(t)\; dt = f(x)$$
while
$$ \int_0^x \dfrac{d}{dt} f(t)\; dt = f(x) - f(0) $$

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this can be useful: *under some conditions* (see, for instance, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule) we have:
$$ \frac{d}{dt} \int_{a}^{b} f(x,t) dx = \int_{a}^{b}  \frac{\partial}{\partial t} f(x,t) dx  $$

Answer (score 1):

Technically, $F(x)$ is *an* anti-derivative of $f(x)$. The function $f(x)$ can have many anti-derivatives, which is why the *general* anti-derivative has the arbitrary constant $C$ added onto it. Each one of those anti-derivatives share the same derivative, $f(x)$.

If you choose the right anti-derivative, the one where $C=0$, then the equality is true. But the equality is not true for most of the values of $C$.

The equation you wrote is not true since by convention $\int f(x)dx$ is taken to mean the general anti-derivative